# Prevent click event during animation

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my code below i've made three buttons that can move when you click on em, but if you click on em during the animation it can still trigger the `update()` event.

Is there a way to make sure that you can't press the buttons during the animation?

I've tried setting flags to prevent the update but I can't figure out a way to make it work without having to double click the buttons.

Another option would be to have a `setTimeout` but I'm unsure if this could cause some synchronization issue.

Here's the code:

```js
update(new Date().getFullYear(), 0);

function update(year, speed) {

 var t = d3.transition().duration(speed);

 var svg = d3.select("svg");

 var result = [(year -1).toString(), (year).toString(), (year +1).toString()];

 var buttons = svg.selectAll(".button").data(result, d => d)

 buttons.exit().transition(t)
  .attr("x", d => +d > year ? 240 : -60)
  .style("opacity", 0)
  .remove()

 buttons.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "button")
  .style("opacity", 0)
  .attr("width", 70)
  .attr("height", 25)
  .attr("y", 15)
  .attr("x", d => +d > year ? 240 : -60)
  .attr("value", d => d)
  .merge(buttons)
 .transition(t)
  .style("opacity", 1)
  .attr("x", (_, i) => 15 + 75 * i)
  .attr("fill", d => +d == year ? "#666" : "#ddd")

 var onclick = d3.selectAll(".button")
  .on("click", function() {
   update(+(d3.select(this).attr("value")), 750)
  })
}
```

```css
body {
 padding-top: 35px;
 margin: auto;
 width: 550px;
 font: 12px monospace;
}
svg {
 width: 250px;
 height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg class="buttons"></svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `speed` is the total duration of the transition. You can use a variable outside the `update` function that gate keeps the `update`

```js
let inTransition = false;

update(new Date().getFullYear(), 0);

function update(year, speed) {

    if (!inTransition) {

         inTransition = true;

         setTimeout(() => { inTransition = false; }, speed);

          var t = d3.transition().duration(speed);

          var svg = d3.select("svg");

          var result = [(year -1).toString(), (year).toString(), (year +1).toString()];

          var buttons = svg.selectAll(".button").data(result, d => d)

          buttons.exit().transition(t)
            .attr("x", d => +d > year ? 240 : -60)
            .style("opacity", 0)
            .remove()

          buttons.enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "button")
            .style("opacity", 0)
            .attr("width", 70)
            .attr("height", 25)
            .attr("y", 15)
            .attr("x", d => +d > year ? 240 : -60)
            .attr("value", d => d)
            .merge(buttons)
          .transition(t)
            .style("opacity", 1)
            .attr("x", (_, i) => 15 + 75 * i)
            .attr("fill", d => +d == year ? "#666" : "#ddd")

          var onclick = d3.selectAll(".button")
            .on("click", function() {
              update(+(d3.select(this).attr("value")), 750)
            })
    }
}
```

```css
body {
 padding-top: 35px;
 margin: auto;
 width: 550px;
 font: 12px monospace;
}
svg {
 width: 250px;
 height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg class="buttons"></svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

d3 has events for that. (Reference: https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_on)

You have to disable pointer events when transition on start, then enable pointer events when transition on end. (Also you can bind and unbind click event on start and on end)

Check it out:

```js
update(new Date().getFullYear(), 0);

function update(year, speed) {

  var t = d3.transition().duration(speed);

  var svg = d3.select("svg");

  var result = [(year - 1).toString(), (year).toString(), (year + 1).toString()];

  var buttons = svg.selectAll(".button").data(result, d => d)

  buttons.exit().transition(t)
    .attr("x", d => +d > year ? 240 : -60)
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .remove()

  buttons.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "button")
    .style("opacity", 0)
    .attr("width", 70)
    .attr("height", 25)
    .attr("y", 15)
    .attr("x", d => +d > year ? 240 : -60)
    .attr("value", d => d)
    .merge(buttons)
    .transition(t)
    .on("start", function() {
      document.getElementById("buttons").style.pointerEvents = "none";
    })
    .on("end", function() {
      document.getElementById("buttons").style.pointerEvents = "all";
    })
    .style("opacity", 1)
    .attr("x", (_, i) => 15 + 75 * i)
    .attr("fill", d => +d == year ? "#666" : "#ddd")

  var onclick = d3.selectAll(".button")
    .on("click", function() {
      update(+(d3.select(this).attr("value")), 750)
    })
}
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 35px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 550px;
  font: 12px monospace;
}

svg {
  width: 250px;
  height: 55px;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg id="buttons" class="buttons"></svg>
```